# SQL Server Update Query says table already exits

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have two tables in my database - `MPRS` and `ALL_SSC`. I want to update the `ALL_SSC` table with data from `MPRS` and in Access (where I test my SQL) it works.

However, when I run it in my VB 2010 program on the SQL Server database, it says table `MPRS` already exists.

I know it does! I'm not trying to create it. I'm updating `FROM` it... any ideas where this SQL is wrong?

```
SQL = "UPDATE ALL_SSC LEFT JOIN MPRS ON MPRS.MPAN = ALL_SSC.MPAN1 SET ALL_SSC.PC1 = Format([mprs].[pc],'00'), ALL_SSC.MSPCDC1 = Mid([mprs].[PC_EFD],7,4) & Mid([mprs].[PC_EFD],4,2) & Mid([mprs].[PC_EFD],1,2), ALL_SSC.MTSC1 = [mprs].[MTC], ALL_SSC.MSMCDC1 = Mid([mprs].[MTC_EFD],7,4) & Mid([mprs].[MTC_EFD],4,2) & Mid([mprs].[MTC_EFD],1,2), ALL_SSC.LLF1 = [mprs].[LLF], ALL_SSC.SUPPLIER1 = [mprs].[SUPPLIER], ALL_SSC.REGI1 = Mid([mprs].[SSD],7,4) & Mid([mprs].[SSD],4,2) & Mid([mprs].[SSD],1,2), ALL_SSC.ENG_STATUS1 = 0 WHERE (((ALL_SSC.MPAN1) Is Not Null) AND ([mprs].[ENERG_STATUS]='E'));"
cmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, cNN)
Try
    Try
    If cNN.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        cNN.Open()
    End If

    Catch exCnn As Exception
    MsgBox(exCnn.Message)
    End Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Cannot continue. " & ex.Message)
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

Comment: You should try taking pieces out of the query until the error stops, and then you will know which piece is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have accidentally used variable "sSQL" when you meant to use "SQL".
Yet another example of why meaningful variable names are important.

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder and Gordon for your help. The variable name is something I should have spotted myself, but just goes to show an independent pair of eyes is priceless. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a `JOIN` with `UPDATE` in SQL Server is:

```
UPDATE a
    SET PC1 = . . .
    FROM ALL_SSC a LEFT JOIN
         MPRS m
         ON m.MPAN = a.MPAN1
    WHERE . . .;
```

That is, you need a `FROM` clause and it comes after the `SET`.

Comment: Thanks - i'l give it a try... guess that's the difference between Access and SQL server...

Comment: odd.... I got the SQL to work in SQL Server, but then I apply it in VB 2010 I still get "There is already an object named 'MPRS' in the database."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon for your help. One or two other changes needed to move from Access SQL to SQL Server, but this is the SQL i ended up with working in SQL Server.

```
    UPDATE a
    SET 
    a.PC1 = '0' + m.[pc], 
    a.MSPCDC1 = substring(m.[PC_EFD],7,4) + substring(m.[PC_EFD],4,2) + substring(m.[PC_EFD],1,2), 
    a.MTSC1 = m.[MTC], 
    a.MSMCDC1 = substring(m.[MTC_EFD],7,4) +substring(m.[MTC_EFD],4,2) + substring(m.[MTC_EFD],1,2), 
    a.LLF1 = m.[LLF], 
    a.SUPPLIER1 = m.[SUPPLIER], 
    a.REGI1 = substring(m.[SSD],7,4) + substring(m.[SSD],4,2) + substring(m.[SSD],1,2),
    a.ENG_STATUS1 = 0 

    FROM [myDataBase].[dbo].ALL_SSC a LEFT JOIN
         [myDataBase].[dbo].MPRS m
         ON m.MPAN = a.MPAN1

    WHERE (((a.MPAN1) Is Not Null) AND (m.[ENERG_STATUS]='E'));
```

However, When I execute the exact same code on the database via VB 2010, I get the same failure message. This is the vb code

```
For iMPAN As Integer = 1 To 3
'mpan - energised
SQL = "UPDATE a SET a.PC" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  '0' + m.[pc], a.MSPCDC" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  substring(m.[PC_EFD],7,4) + substring(m.[PC_EFD],4,2) + substring(m.[PC_EFD],1,2), a.MTSC" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  m.[MTC], a.MSMCDC" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  substring(m.[MTC_EFD],7,4) +substring(m.[MTC_EFD],4,2) + substring(m.[MTC_EFD],1,2), a.LLF" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  m.[LLF], a.SUPPLIER" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  m.[SUPPLIER], a.REGI" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  substring(m.[SSD],7,4) + substring(m.[SSD],4,2) + substring(m.[SSD],1,2), a.ENG_STATUS" + iMPAN.ToString + " =  0 FROM ALL_SSC a LEFT JOIN MPRS m ON m.MPAN = a.MPAN1 WHERE (((a.MPAN" + iMPAN.ToString + ") Is Not Null) AND (m.[ENERG_STATUS]='E'));"
Debug.Print(SQL)

cmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, cNN)
Try
    Try
    If cNN.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        cNN.Open()
    End If

    Catch exCnn As Exception

    MsgBox(exCnn.Message)
    End Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)

    MsgBox("Cannot continue. " & ex.Message)
    Exit Sub
End Try
Next
```

Comment: As a test, I simplified the SQl to updating one field. "UPDATE ALL_SSC SET ALL_SSC.PC1 = 'Z' FROM MPRS LEFT JOIN ALL_SSC ON MPRS.MPAN = ALL_SSC.MPAN1 WHERE (((ALL_SSC.MPAN1) Is Not Null) AND (MPRS.[ENERG_STATUS]='E')); " works in SQL Server, produces "There is already an object named 'MPRS' in the database" in VB2010... getting really hacked off with this.

Comment: I can't believe it was something so simple/stupid... please post that as an answer so I can accept it! OMG I feel elated and ridiculous at the same time... Thank you SOOooooo much! Combination of correct format from Gordon, and correct common sense from Crowcoder!